# Getting from Func<T, T, bool> + T instance to Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, expression

If I have a `Func<T, T, bool>` that tells me how to compare two Ts as in

```
var comparer = (a, b) => 
    a.IdPart1 == b.IdPart1 && a.IdPart2 == b.IdPart2;
```

And I want to use this and a concrete instance of T to create a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` to be used as a predicate for Where() such as

```
T instance = GetSomeT();
TRepository.GetAll().Where(x => 
    x.IdPart1 == instance.IdPart1 && x.IdPart2 == instance.IdPart2);
```

but of course dynamically so that I could instead write

```
var predicate = something depending on comparer and instance;
TRepository.GetAll().Where(predicate);
```

Is it possible?

Even cooler would be if I could dynamically create the predicate just from T with equals between all properties with KeyAttribute and `and` in between, so that I wouldn't need the comparer, just T.

Is *that* possible? :)

Comment: Is [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) is what you looking for?

Comment: If something's asking for an `Expression<Func<...>>`, it's usually because it wants to be able (as here) to translate it into a different form (SQL). If it's unable to perform the transformation, it'll either error or end up applying the predicate far later than desired - I can't remember what Linq-to-Entities does, but it's choices would be to fail or to retrieve *all* entities and perform the comparison in code. Not ideal.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever AFAIK, if EF doesn't understand some `Expression`, it throws an exception. I think that's much more reasonable that doing something like retrieving the whole table and filtering it in memory.

Comment: @svick - That's kind of what I expected - I was just trying to point out that there are only two real approaches available to any code *asking* for an expression and intending to transform it that receives something untransformable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get `comparer` as `Expression<Func<T, T, bool>>`, then you can use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to do this.

Something like:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, Foo, bool>> comparer =
    (a, b) => a.IdPart1 == b.IdPart1 && a.IdPart2 == b.IdPart2;

Foo instance = …;

Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = x => comparer.Invoke(x, instance);
var expandedPredicate = predicate.Expand();

var result = FooRepository.GetAll().Where(expandedPredicate);
```

The `Expand()` part is important, because that's where LINQKit's “magic” happens. A slightly different syntax to do the same thing is to use `AsExpandable()` instead:

```
var result = FooRepository.GetAll().AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
T instance = GetSomeT();
Predicate<T> MyPredicate = x => comparer(x, instance);
TRepository.GetAll().Where(MyPredicate);
```

---

Taking in account the comment gave below, here is how you make a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

```
T instance = GetSomeT();
Expression<Func<T, bool>> Exp = x => comparer(x, instance);
TRepository.GetAll().Where(Exp);
```

That's exactly the same, just with different var type.

In short you can just:

```
TRepository.GetAll().Where(x => comparer(x, instance));
```

Comment: `MyPredicate` is not an `Expression`, so it can't be translated to SQL (or whatever the repository is using).

Comment: Now `Exp` is an expression, but it still can't be translated to an expression, because it invokes a delegate that is unknown to the repository.